# PC crashed. Can I install Ubuntu onto my PC via my Android smartphone?

Tags: system-installation, android

As the title states, my computer went all blah on me and I'm trying to fix it. I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed prior but now both are not wanting to start.

Is it possible to download Ubuntu onto my phone and use it like an USB and boot that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need a rooted device!

The app drive Droid will do the rest (on most phones, not all are compatible)!

Here's a link to the app on the play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid

Comment: Are u talking about installing it on my phone? Im trying to install onto pc from my phone. Using my phone as a usb thumb drive. Im trying to see if thats possible.

Comment: Ok yes u are. Just went there. Thank u if thus works correctly u are my hero lol

Comment: Ok i installed this and downloaded the iso from ubuntu and the program shows it but wont allow me to click on it to select it. Its greyed out

Comment: @AzariusJenkins is your phone rooted?

Comment: and thank you again for that. it helped out SOOOO much... i actually kept it and am using it with other pc's to fix them as well